# javascript code, create a function that returns a boolean depending on whether or not a number is even or not?

Tags: javascript

```js
var i = 1;
var numberCounter = 0
function isEven(num){
  if (i % numberCounter === 0) {
    console.log('true');
  } else { console.log('false');
}        
console.log(isEven(50));

console.log(isEven(75));

console.log(isEven(-1));
```

Im not exactly sure where i went wrong here, i am trying to create a function that returns a boolean depending on whether or not a number is even or not.

Comment: Welcome!
You are not using the passed `num` in your function.
Your function is not returning anything -> `undefined` will be logged when `isEven(50)`, for example.
"Even" is a number that divides by two without remainder (alt: remainder is zero), so:
`isEven(num) { return !(num%2); }` (when the remainder is zero, `!` flips it to `true`, anything else - to `false`).
Pay attention to indentation - computer don't mine, but it helps humans.

Answer (score 0):

in order to check if a number is even or not you should check to see if the modulo of 2 with the number is 0. other then that in order to return a value from a function you should use the keyword `return`. therefor the `isEven` function should be:

```js
function isEven(num){
  return num % 2 === 0;
}        
console.log(isEven(50));

console.log(isEven(75));

console.log(isEven(-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

(even number) % 2 = 0 and with `!` you will the 0 as 1 in boolean.

% => module

/ => division

```
const isEven = number => !(number % 2)

isEven(2) // true


const isOdd = number => !!(number % 2)

isEven(3) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
var i = 1;
var numberCounter = 0
function isEven(num){
  if (i % numberCounter === 0) {
    console.log('true');
  } else { console.log('false');
}
```

Note that i is equal to 0 and numberCounter is equal to 0. No matter which number is passed in your function, its value won't be considered.

You want to define if a number is odd or even. As a matter of fact the number you want to estimate is the parameter of the function.
A basic definition would be that an odd number can be divided by 2. It means that the remainder of the division is equal to 0.

the if statement concerns the num (passed as parameter) and the remainder.
I took your code and modified it. Saar Davidson answer is much more better and effective (in a single line).

```
function isEven(num){
  if (num % 2 === 0) {
    console.log('true');
    return true;
  } else { 
    console.log('false');
    return false;
  }
}
```